# Run a unit test with the 'Marketing User' enabled

Tags: apex, unit-test, campaign

I have a unit test that needs to run as a user with the 'Marketing User' permission turned on because the code needs to create a Campaign.  I tried the following:

```
 User u = [SELECT ID FROM User WHERE ID = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
 u.UserPermissionsMarketingUser   = true;
 update u; 
 system.assertEquals(true,Schema.sObjectType.Campaign.isCreateable());
```

But the assertion fails unless I actually go to the user record and manually check the 'Marketing User' box.

Does anyone have an idea on how I can make this assertion pass during a unit test without having to tell the person running the test to go manually change their user record?

Comment: hmm -- best practice would be to mock a User (rather than use the running user), then do `system.runAs(theMockedUser)` for your tests

Answer (score 1):

Check your org to find out the name of the profile that has it enabled by default. Use that profile name when you run your query for a user. If there isn't one, then you'll probably find it simplest to approach it from a permission set and group approach when you run your query and later do your assertion.